# How to differentiate events between browser back button click and text link click in a website using JS(without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, events, browser, back, browser-history

How do I differentiate the events triggered on back button click and a click on text link within the website?

The below `onpopstate()` executes every time when I navigate through back and forward buttons OR within the site.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
};
```

I need a solution without jQuery. Help would be appreciated.